# Why my coding has broken from UTF-8 in python? | PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, utf-8

I made a program on Python at the root is the file words.txt and main.py, after starting main.py it should print the words from words.txt, words in words.txt are Russian! Each with a new line.

The contents main.py:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    f = open('words.txt')

    line = f.readline()

    while line:

        print (line),

        line = f.readline()

    f.close()
```

Example of words in words.txt:

```
    Машина

    Работа

    Дом
```

Prints something like that:

```
    СЏС‚СЊ

    СЏС…РѕРЅС‚

    СЏС…С‚-РєР»СѓР±

    СЏС…С‚Р°

    СЏС…С‚РѕРІР»Р°РґРµР»РµС†

    СЏС…С‚СЃРјРµРЅ
```

I'm working in PyCharm.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra comma after `print(line)`. Typo perhaps?

Comment: no, sorry, it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file *words.txt* was saved with UTF-8 encoding, then open it accordingly:

```
f = open("words.txt", encoding="utf-8")
```

There's also the possibility that it still fails, in case the STDOUT channel uses an encoding different from UTF-8.
In that case you need to change some PyCharm setting.
But I guess that is rather unlikely.